# Discord py buttons time out and when re-initialised it still times out after a couple iterations

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, timeout

I have a python discord bot that does buttons on embeds. The program loops every hour to re-initialise the buttons back onto the embed because I found just doing it once still times-out.

```
import numpy as np

import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import sqlite3
import random
import datetime
import GlobalEx as BKED
from discord import app_commands
from datetime import date
from discord.ui import Button, View
import json
import Embeds as EMCB
from Logger import LogCSV
from ast import literal_eval
import time
@tasks.loop(seconds=60*60)
async def EmbedChecks(self):
   b1 = Button(label="Enter", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green, custom_id=f"{a[2]}|giveawayenter")
   b2 = Button(label="Leave", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, custom_id=f"{a[2]}|giveawayexit")
   b3 = Button(label="Get Roles",style=discord.ButtonStyle.url,url="https://patreon.com/AfterHours_OFFL")

   async def button_callback(interaction: discord.Interaction):
      #Some button stuff here which works
   b1.callback = button_callback
   b2.callback = button_callback
   #print("integrate buttons to view")
   view = View()
   view.add_item(b1)
   view.add_item(b2) 
   view.add_item(b3)
   channel = self.bot.get_channel(a[3])
   msg = await channel.fetch_message(a[2])
   await msg.edit(view=view)
```

Comment: This reads like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), it's not usually necessary to "reinitialize buttons" in Discord. What's the exact behaviour you're experiencing when interacting with each button? Are the interactions failing completely? Does your button callback have proper handling for your button's custom IDs?

Comment: Interactions fail completely, the definition doesn't even start

Answer (score 1):

The fix was apparently just `View(timeout=None)`, you have to define the timeout period because discord natively times out the buttons in 3 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Try classifying the buttons in a View. Then add the view to the bot.

### **Adding them to a view**

```py
class MyView(discord.ui.View):
    # Your code
```

Or leave it as it is

### **Adding the view to the bot**

`commands.Bot` has an attribute that let programmers add a view to it and that view to keep working even if restarted.

```py
await bot.add_view(MyView)
```

*Note: I never used `add_view` in my bots, so any other things go to the [documentation](https://discordpy.rtfd.com/)

Comment: That didn't work for me but I did find the fix